# jQuery: Put dynamically generated input values to span/div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create form for printing with dynamically generated inputs.
Contents of the fields is shown later in PreviewDiv.
It works fine as long as I specify where they should be, for example:

```
$('#Prw_CapacityA_1').text($('#CapacityA_1').val());
$('#Prw_CapacityB_1').text($('#CapacityB_1').val());
$('#Prw_CapacityC_1').text($('#CapacityC_1').val());
```

But if the user creates 100 fields this would be a lot of code to write. 
There must be other methods to fix this dynamically, for example:

```
$('#Prw_CapacityA_'+ counter).text($('#CapacityA_'+ counter).val());
```

[Here's the js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/valder/63umF/)

Comment: alerts "blah blah 5".. seriously..? -__-

Comment: may look better with "No more rows to add. Max 5" )))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using [attribute starts with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) to select the elements starting with the specific id's and then loop through them using the [each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/) function.

There is no need to have html within your preview table. You can generate it when the user clicks on preview. Modified [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/63umF/15/)

```
$('#PreviewButton').click(function(){

    var capB = $('td input[id^=CapacityB_]');
    var capC = $('td input[id^=CapacityC_]');
    var table = $("#AddFieldsToPreviewDiv");
    table.empty(); //build table everytime user previews so that previously appended values are removed 
    table.append('<tr><td>ID</td><td>Text 1</td><td>Text 2</td><td>Text 3</td></tr>');

    $('td input[id^=CapacityA_]').each(function(i){
        table.append('<tr><td>#'+(i + 1)
                      +'</td><td>'+$(this).val()
                      +'</td><td>'+$(capB[i]).val()
                     +'</td><td>'+$(capC[i]).val()
                     +'</td></tr>');
    });
    // Show PreviewDiv and hide FormDiv if PreviewButton clicked
    $('#PreviewDiv').show();
    $('#FormDiv').hide();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, it was a good solution, it works well.

Answer (score 0):

You could try giving them a unique class (Normally I'd suggest ID but you're using one) say a class of "getinfo"

You could then try the .each() function

https://api.jquery.com/each/

```
$( ".getinfo" ).each(function( index ) {
var text = $(this).val();
 alert(text);
});
```

This will make an alert box for every element it finds with the class 'getinfo' and then retrieve the value and display it, I hope this gives you a better idea.

If the amount of inputs can change from one page load to the next then you need to use a loop, rather than pulling all the values by 'hand', More code will help better understand what you're trying to achieve and from *what*.